# React Native :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, okhttp

I'm trying to implement a `Trustmanager` for websocket connections in a React Native project by directly adopting the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinmcampos/2cea3d0644e6642f22c2fc396f040842). It requires the `okhttp-ws` module to run.

But, it fails at `:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses`

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$1 found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketProtocol found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader$FrameCallback found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
  Duplicate class okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter$FrameSink found in modules okhttp-3.14.1.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1) and okhttp-ws-3.4.2.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.2)
```

So, I excluded `okhttp` from `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    // compile the ws module
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:+'){
        // exclude the conflicting module
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        // interestingly, it's been excluded here too
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Still, I get the same error. So, I visited the developer docs [link](http://d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors) that the error shows and tried searching for the Class `okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket` in Android Studio. But it only shows some files from cache folder containing the troublesome Class, both of `okhttp` and `ws` modules, which I can't delete these files. For other classes, it just shows files from the `okhttp` module only, which I can't delete either. Is there a workaround to this? What am I missing?

Comment: I'd suggest using precise versions rather than + while you sort this out.  You can't mix versions, so should be using a consistent version of okhttp across the board.

3.14.1 is no longer actively maintained so consider 3.12.12 (legacy java impl), or 4.9.0 (latest supported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSocket is now part of the core library. https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-web-socket/

So you should upgrade to 4.9.0 and stop depending on okhttp-ws, or revert to 3.12.12 (which is a supported legacy branch).

There is a sample here of how to use the WebSocket support in OkHttp https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/slack/src/main/java/okhttp3/slack/SlackApi.java

Or use the built in react-native support https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

Comment: Thanks. I already solved that. But can you please point me to some gist or something with a working code for Android `TrustManager[]` implemented for websockets, preferably to easily adapt and use with React Native?

Comment: added to my answer above, you can adapt the API calls shown above to your requirements.  But since react-native supports websocket, you may not need this at all.

Comment: But React Native doesn't natively support cert based SSL/TLS websocket connections, right? I mean, the `wss` connections?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/aeaf286c77b50a95c4961de0d2355caad8ffa396/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/websocket/WebSocketModule.java